# Why GetXController inheritance not working?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am quite new to flutter.

I have one controller named **LoginController** which extends from **BaseController** but while running the app I am getting the below error.

BasePage Code

```
    class BasePage extends StatelessWidget {
  var baseController = Get.find<BaseController>();

  BasePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  late Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Obx(() {
      return baseController.IsNetworkAvailable.value?child:const NoInternetPage();
    });
  }

  Widget GetWidget() {
    if (baseController.IsNetworkAvailable.value) {
      return child;
    } else {
      return const NoInternetPage();
    }
  }
}
```

here is the LoginPage code snippet

```
   class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key)
    {
    loginController =Get.put(LoginController());

    child=RenderView();
    }
late LoginController loginController;


  TextStyle GetHeadingStyle()
  {
    return const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey,
        fontSize: 20
    );
  }

  Widget RenderView()
  {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30,0,30,0),
          child: Obx((){
            return
              loginController.IsBusy.value?
              const Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 60,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    strokeWidth: 5.0,
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
              ):
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextField(
                      controller: loginController.domainController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Domain',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder())
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextField(
                      controller: loginController.usernameController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder())
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextField(
                      controller: loginController.passwordController,
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder())
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 40,
                    child:
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()=>{
                      loginController.doLogin(LoginSuccess,LoginFailed)
                    },
                      child:const Text('Login'
                          ,style: TextStyle()),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
          })
      ),
    );
  }
  void LoginSuccess() {
    loginController.IsBusy.value = false;
    Get.snackbar("Success", "Login Success",backgroundColor: Colors.green,colorText: Colors.white);
    var storage = GetStorage();
    storage.write("IsLoggedIn", true);
    Get.off(MainPage());
  }
  void LoginFailed()
  {
    loginController.IsBusy.value=false;
    Get.snackbar("Failed", "Login Failed",backgroundColor: Colors.red,colorText: Colors.white);
  }

}
```

Login Controller Code

```
   class LoginController extends BaseController {
  TextEditingController domainController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  LoginController() {}

  void doLogin(Function loginSuccess, Function loginFailed) async {
    if (await checkConnection()) {
      //await RestService().PostRequest(Resources.LOGIN_URL,loginData , loginSuccess, loginFailed);
    }
  }
}
```

Base Controller Code

```
    class BaseController extends GetxController {
  var IsBusy = false.obs;
  var IsNetworkAvailable = false.obs;
  var IsServerDown = false.obs;

  BaseController() {}

  Future<bool> checkConnection(
      {bool setIsBusy = true, bool setNetworkAvailable = true}) async {
    var result = await ConnectivityService.checkConnection();
    bool isConnected = result != ConnectivityResult.none;
    if (setIsBusy) {
      IsBusy.value = isConnected;
    }
    if (setNetworkAvailable) {
      IsNetworkAvailable.value = isConnected;
    }
    return isConnected;
  }
}
```

**Note:** I am assuming initializing **Get.put(LoginController())** should automatically initialize BaseController as well because it inherited from BaseController.

Comment: You need to Put `Get.put(BaseController)` before `Loginpage`

Comment: @SabahatHussainQureshi but BaseController is the Base of Login Controller why should I put in Get?

Comment: You must be really trying to find a `BaseController` in your code instead of a `LoginController`

Comment: Can you show your full `LoginPage`? And please don't put images of code, just the code itself

Answer (score 0):

Try calling BaseController like this in LoginController.

```
   class LoginController extends GetxController {
      TextEditingController domainController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
    
      LoginController() {}
    
      void doLogin(Function loginSuccess, Function loginFailed) async {
      Get.putAsync(() => BaseController().checkConnection()).then((value) {
    if(value == true){
      //do something
    } });
        
      }
    }
```

Comment: Getting error saying **Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'**

Comment: Edited my answer. Kindly check it now.

Comment: How will I get the bool value of the method checkConnection? that is true or false?

Comment: Edited, Check now.

Comment: Bro is it done?

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this still hasn't solved my problem. Whenever I click on the login button without an internet connection it's not replacing my current view to no internet page.